# Upgrade to Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, xubuntu, 18.04

Working on Xubuntu 16.04. I would like to upgrade to 18.04, without reinstall. What are the steps?

Comment: Try these commands: `sudo apt update &&   
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: To tell you the truth, I just did the upgrade from Xubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and now I am regretting it.  Too many errors, video driver issues, and applications that end up on the `apt upgrade` that will not upgrade due to dependency issues.  I would recommend that you wait for the first point release (18.04.1) due out in July of this year, or do a clean install of 18.04.  The normal upgrade command is `do-release-upgrade -d` but I am warning you now that it may not go smooth at all.

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate of existing questions, but the questions linked aren't duplicates - they are about upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, not Xubuntu 18.04. If you're not careful about upgrading Xubuntu, it will be upgraded to Ubuntu.

Comment: I confirm, that this question is NOT a duplicate. Please, unmark it. This is about XUBUNTU, not UBUNTU, and about version 18.04, not 16.04.

Comment: I wrote a freely available article about this: [**How to do a Xubuntu LTS Release Upgrade**](https://hamwaves.com/release-upgrade/en/index.html)